# How do I plot a bunch of vectors in Maple and find the difference and cross product between them?

Tags: maple, cross-product

Title says it all. This is the assignment I'm trying to do.
http://math.rutgers.edu/~shtelen/Teaching/Fall-2013/L1_instr.pdf
Data I need to plot
http://math.rutgers.edu/~shtelen/Teaching/Fall-2013/s251-TF_F13.html

Which package do I use
Need maple to plot a lot of vectors and get difference and cross product

please help

Answer (score 2):

Look at this one:

```
[> with(plots):
   arrow([seq(<(sin(i), cos(i), 1)>, i = 1 .. 50)], axes = boxed);
```

[image]

Comment: Gorgeous! and nice, efficient code... (+1)

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. This might just have to do with my professor, but what do you think I'm suppose to do with all the data points here: http://math.rutgers.edu/~shtelen/Teaching/Fall-2013/s251-TF_F13.html
Do you think he really expects us to plot all 260 vectors? It would take forever to just copy and paste.

Comment: @PhilipRego: I couldn't find that vectors or data points in that page. Are they in L1 or L2?

Comment: I'm sorry it's here: http://math.rutgers.edu/~shtelen/Teaching/Fall-2013/Lab1_DataPage.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HTTP` package of recent Maple to grab that cited data programmatically. The following code worked for me on Windows 7 Pro using each of 64bit Maple 15.01, 16.02, and 17.02.

Note that there are only 259 data sets; it jumps from 142 to 144.

```
restart:

with(StringTools):
with(XMLTools):

(N,str,b):=HTTP:-Get("http://math.rutgers.edu/~shtelen/Teaching/Fall-2013/Lab1_DataPage.htm"):

(n1,n2) := Search("<tr>",str),Search("</table>",str):
newstr:=Drop(Take(str,n2-1),n1-1):
xt:=FromString(cat("<html>",newstr,"</html>")):
S:=indets(xt,specfunc(anything,_XML_tr)):

# Now create Vdata a list lists, with an inner list containing a p,q,r triple
Vdata:=sort([seq([parse(op([1,2],s)),
                  eval([[p],[q],[r]],[parse(op([2,1],s))])[]],
                 s in S)]):

Vdata[1];

     [1, [15, 18, 14], [11, 23, 20], [13, 18, 13]]

Vdata[1][2],Vdata[1][3],Vdata[1][4];

        [15, 18, 14], [11, 23, 20], [13, 18, 13]


Vdata[5];

       [5, [11, 11, 13], [17, 8, 15], [15, 8, 8]]

# How many of them are there?
nops(Vdata);

                          259

# We can also index into Vdata from the other end.
Vdata[-1];

    [260, [18, 19, 13], [21, 24, 12], [20, 22, 17]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`with(LinearAlgebra);` is the package needed for the Cross Product to work.

`CrossProduct(V1,V2);` computes the cross product of the vectors $V1$ and $V2$. (Alternatively, `V1 &x V2;` also will give you the same result.)

Vectors can be defined in Maple using `<>`. For example, this is a vector: `<1,2,3>;`

The difference can be calculated normally, such as:

`vec1:=<1,2,3>; vec2:=<2,3,4>; vec1-vec2;`