# LinAlg Vector Graphing

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm looking for a graphing calculator to graph vectors - NOT vector fields. A Google search turned up many great calculators with vector-valued function capabilities. However, I'm looking for something to help me visualize the concepts I'm learning in Linear Algebra, e.g. that combinations of certain vectors lie in a plane.

An example of what I'm looking for: the parameter $[3, 6, 5]$ would be represented as a vector from the origin to the
point $(3, 6,  5)$

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use Maple to do this job. Here, are the codes, you can count on them:

```
[> with(plots):
   arrow([3,6,5], axes = boxed, difference, color = blue, shape = cylindrical_arrow, fringe = 'red');
```

[image]

For a relevant well-design post see this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/509428/8581).

Comment: This needs a thumb's up! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: I concur, love these graphics! +1

Comment: Nice truly nice! +1

Answer (score 0):

GeoGebra can do dynamic Vectors and Planes (and much more) in 2D and 3D, eg

http://web.geogebra.org/?command=v=(3,6,5);PerpendicularPlane[(0,0,0),v]#3d